# MVVM Bind Enum and Enum description To Devexpress LookUpEdit

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, enums, devexpress

I want to bind Enum and Enum description to devexpress dxg:LookUpEdit but unable to do that. I am able to aceive the same result with ComboBox but I want the to show that in a grid which look up edit does.
This is what the code looks like. I have a Converter whcih converts the Enum to enum description.

```
 <dxg:LookUpEdit Name="lookUpEdit" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}"
                                        AutoComplete="True" AutoPopulateColumns="False" PopupWidth="250">
                    <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <dxg:GridControl Name="PART_GridControl">
                                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Filter" FieldName="Name" Width="100" />
                                    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" Width="100">
                                        <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                              <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}"></Run>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" />
                                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                            </dxg:GridControl>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                </dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the EnumItemsSource as follows(for this source, you can set a custom converter to transform enum-values):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EnumToStringConverter x:Key="enumToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<dxg:LookUpEdit HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                AutoPopulateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{dxe:EnumItemsSource EnumType={x:Type local:MyEnum}, NameConverter={StaticResource enumToStringConverter}, UseNumericEnumValue=True}"
                >
    <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <dxg:GridControl Name="PART_GridControl">
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id" Header="ID"/>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Value" Header="DESCRIPTION"/>
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" ShowGroupPanel="False"/>
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
</dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

Comment: this shows two columns id and value. I want to to show value and description. description will come from enumToStringConverter. Also I want to know how will SelectedItem going to work.